# Why is this returning 0?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom captcha generator. In short, the server returns a URL of an image through AJAX and keeps in session storage an association with the image.

**PHP:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_animal_captcha', 'set_animal_captcha' );
$capdir = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/captcha/';
$capmap = array ( 'cat'  => $capdir . 'Captcha_Cat.png',
                  'dog'  => $capdir . 'Captcha_Dog.png',
                  'fish' => $capdir . 'Captcha_Fish.png' );
function set_animal_captcha ( )
{
    // returns image url of random animal and stores in session storage
    // a reference to that animal
    $randAnimal = array_rand($capmap,1);
    $_SESSION['randAnimal'] = $randAnimal;
    die(json_encode($capmap[$randAnimal]));
}
```

**JS:**

```
function capHandler ( imgid )
{
    // imgid: id of the image 

    this.imgid = imgid;
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.formData.append('action', 'set_animal_captcha');
    this.set = function ( )
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function ( animalUrl ) { alert(animalUrl); },
            error: function ( ) { alert("Error in getting captcha image") },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that it's alerting

```
0
```

and I can't figure out why. Because I know the `success` function is being called, there must be something wrong with the PHP.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's developer tools to see what the Ajax request is actually returning?

Comment: Instead of alerting, try `console.log( animalUrl );` May be better suited for outputting the result.

Comment: declare `$capmap` as global within the function - ie: `global $capmap;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you setting `$capmap` outside of `set_animal_captcha()`? If you really must keep it outside `set_animal_captcha`, then set `$capmap` as a global inside your function. Like this:

```
function set_animal_captcha ( )
{
    global $capmap;
    // returns image url of random animal and stores in session storage
    // a reference to that animal
    $randAnimal = array_rand($capmap,1);
    $_SESSION['randAnimal'] = $randAnimal;
    die(json_encode($capmap[$randAnimal]));
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and also changed the `die` statement to `die("lkajdkasldaskljd");` but am still getting `0` returned .... Maybe my server has cached this value to send back?

Comment: You need to check what is returned from your ajax request, alert is not reliable. console.log can return a much more detailed info.

Comment: @MarkKrapivner `console.log` is printing `0` as well

Comment: I'm starting to think your code doesn't reach set_animal_captcha( ), do you have a step by step debugger like xdebug?

Comment: @MarkKrapivner The problem is that I forgot to add `data: this.formData` as a parameter in my `$.ajax` call. Voted you as best answer because you pointed out another problem.

Answer (score -2):

Please die the statement from where you are returning some value by putting this:

```
 die();
```